# How to correctly render multiple apps on the main page

Tags: django, templates, web, view, render

So I'm currently learning to use Django, and I'm wondering how to correctly split up parts of the functionality while still displaying it on the main page.

For example, I want the header + navigation, a calendar and recent blog articles on the main index page.
On the view article page I'd for example have the header + nav, the calendar and a single article with a comment section.

Now reading the tutorials, if I understand them correctly, I'd split the functionality in a header app, a calendar app and the blog app itself while glueing it together with a core app.

But what I don't understand is how to render apps/other views in the main app. All the ways I found only specify templates itself or look very hacky, so apparently that doesn't seem to be the common way to go.

Answer (score 0):

So there are multiple views are work here:

1.The views that you want to show

2.The view that will render the page, displaying all of the views (lets call this the 'main view'.

The first step is to import all of the other views / models into the views.py file that the main view resides in.

```
from blog.models import Post
from calendar.models import Calendar
```

Now you can edit your mainview to acces this data. For example:

```
class Mainview(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/homepage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #This will only show the latest post
        data['posts'] = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
        data['calendar'] = Calendar.objects.all()
        return data
```

Now you can acces the data from the other apps in your template using the {{ }} tags, for example - you could do something like this:

```
{% for post object in post %}
   {{ post.title }}
   {{ post.content}}
{% endfor %}
```